# Is it possible to save and open network paths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering if its possible for a web application with spring/spring-boot, to manipulate, open and save files in their intranet network with access to the path.. Basically the app should save the path to a file and allow the browser to open and save/upload to a folder.

As far as I'm concerned, JavaScript doesn't allow access to the local pc filesystem. So I'm wondering how would these requirements be fulfilled in a web app. Would it need some kind of plugin?

Comment: a) nope b) file input c) download attribute

Comment: How can he open the file if its in the intranet network?

Comment: Is it a mapped network drive?

Comment: In Most cases, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options come in my mind:

- You could use FTP in your Spring Application to store the file.
- You can mount a NFS share to your server and then just store the file there.
- You can use OneDrive API to store the files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Could I allow the hyperlinks to be onedrive or googledrive links, instead?